# Execute and capture the results in the terminal of a ruby file using php

Tags: php, ruby, exec

I have added php script to run my ruby file but to no success. I run my php script in its php directory.

```
$command = "ruby /home/user/ruby-grok/examples/result.rb";
$out = shell_exec($command);
```

It does not display the results of the ruby file. But when I run the command outside php it works.

Expected result is to display information in the terminal and write the results to a file.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What's actually happening?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to ask a clear question,  if you want to get answers. Include an error description and what you are expecting.